# Is it true that Elementry OS is quite vulnerable to Mass Surveillance programs like PRISM?

Tags: release-loki, security

I've been told that Elementry OS is built from Ubuntu and Debian.Many of the digital rights webistes were not recommending UBUNTU derivative distros for privacy since Canonical’s Ubuntu contains Amazon ads and data leaks by default.

GNU/Linux distributions based on Ubuntu are also currently not recommended due to several other reasons.

**IS THIS TRUE ?!!**

Resouce:
[@Please go to Operating system sub-catagory](https://prism-break.org/en/categories/gnu-linux/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Amazon shopping component has nothing to do with "PRISM" or other mass surveillance programs (though the amazon component of Ubuntu is hardly something I would call mass surveillance). But anything you do online can be tracked no matter what system you use.

Elementary does not have the Amazon shopping tracking component.